# Пересылка сообщений с изображениями aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Как в python переслать изображение от одного пользователя к другому (мне) с помощью библиотеки aiogram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простым методом будет `message.forward`или `message.copy_to`

Разница между методами в том, что `message.forward` показывает откуда было переслано сообщение, в то время как `message.copy_to` присылает новое сообщение, копию оригинального.

Пример в коде:

```
to_id = 1234  # твой user_id

async def handler(message: types.Message):
    
    await message.forward(to_id)
    # или
    await message.copy_to(to_id)
    # или
    await message.send_copy(to_id) # аналог .copy_to()
```